# codeigniter use variable from custom library into controller then views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a custom library and need to pass some variables under specific method to my controller, then views.

Library code

```
  Class Data {
function dviews($sitedata) {
$site1 = "www.site1.com";
$site2 = "site2.com";
}
}
```

My controller file

```
class Webs extends CI_Controller {
public function index()
    {
         $this->load->library('Data');
        $data = $this->Data->dviews();
        $this->load->view('pages/websites', $data);

    }
}
```

and I pass the $data array using print_r on views.

is that correct or there is another way to get the list of these vars from library file and pass them?

Comment: Your `dviews` method returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting variable inside method but **returning nothing**, so

**Modify**

```
Class Data {
  function dviews($sitedata) {
    $site1 = "www.site1.com";
    $site2 = "site2.com";
  }
}
```

**To**

```
Class Data {
  function dviews($sitedata) {
   return array( 'site1' => "www.site1.com", 'site2' => "site2.com");
 }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class Webs extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->library('Data');

        $data = $this->Data->dviews();

        // now print_r($data); will have array which you returned

        $this->load->view('pages/websites', $data);
    }
}
```

and in your **view**, `pages/websites.php` you can access like below

```
<?php echo $site1; ?>
<?php echo $site2; ?>
```